# Discord.py: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Tags: python, json, discord.py

I'm trying to make a bot that re-adds the "muted" role to whoever rejoined the server while muted. Here's the .py code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_member_join(member):
    with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
        data = json.load(fp)
        mute = discord.utils.get(member.guild.roles, name = "mute role")
        if member.id in data['muted']:
            await member.add_roles(mute)

class Moderation(commands.Cog):
    @bot.command()
    async def mute(ctx, member:discord.Member):
        mute = ctx.guild.get_role(THE ROLE'S ID)
        await member.edit(roles=[mute])
        with open('users.json', 'r+') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
            if member.id not in data['muted']:
                data['muted'].append(member.id)
                json.dump(data, fp)
```

And here's the .json code:

```
{
    "muted" : []
}
```

Every time I mute someone, I get an error saying "JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)" and the person's ID won't save. I've looked on many other posts for answers but none of them answered anything.

Answer (score 1):

When you open with `r+` and read it, you're now seeking to the end. Then, when you write to it, you're actually appending to the file rather than overwriting it.

You can see the behavior here:

```py
>>> with open('_delete_me.txt', 'w') as f:
...   f.write('this is a test.')
... 
15
>>> with open('_delete_me.txt', 'r+') as f:
...   print(f.read())
...   f.write('another test')
... 
this is a test.
5
>>> with open('_delete_me.txt', 'r') as f:
...   print(f.read())
... 
this is a test.another test
```

To overwrite it, it's possible to just open the file again in `w` write mode:

```py
        with open('users.json', 'r') as fp:
            data = json.load(fp)
        if member.id not in data['muted']:
            data['muted'].append(member.id)
        with open('users.json', 'w') as fp:
            json.dump(data, fp)
```